# Have content below click to fade div move up when it disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!document.getElementById('Ad-Detect-js')){
        document.getElementById('RLAD').style.display='block';
    }

    var RLAD = document.getElementById('RLAD');
        document.getElementById('RLAD-wrapper').onclick = function(){
            if(!document.getElementById('Ad-Detect-js')){
                RLAD.className = RLAD.className ? 'fade' : 'fade';
            }
        }
</script>
```

That's the script I'm using to remove a certain div once clicked. The issue is that the content below stays in place, leaving a gap where the div resided. Is there a way to ensure that everything below is shifted up?

Comment: The question would be more clearly if you made a fiddle or a snipset

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transitions on the display: property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you remove (or use `display: none`) the block once it's done fading out. You could make use of the `transitionend` event :

```js
if (!document.getElementById('Ad-Detect-js')) {
  document.getElementById('RLAD').style.display = 'block';
}

var RLAD = document.getElementById('RLAD');
document.getElementById('RLAD-wrapper').onclick = function() {
  if (!document.getElementById('Ad-Detect-js')) {
    RLAD.className = RLAD.className ? 'fade' : 'fade';
  }
}

RLAD.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
 this.remove();
});
```

```css
#RLAD {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}
```

```html
<button id="RLAD-wrapper">
click me
</button>
<div id="RLAD"></div>
<div>
content
</div>
```

Or with a timer set to the duration of the fade-out animation :

```js
if (!document.getElementById('Ad-Detect-js')) {
  document.getElementById('RLAD').style.display = 'block';
}

var RLAD = document.getElementById('RLAD');
document.getElementById('RLAD-wrapper').onclick = function() {
  if (!document.getElementById('Ad-Detect-js')) {
    RLAD.className = RLAD.className ? 'fade' : 'fade';
    setTimeout(function() {
      RLAD.remove();
    }, 300);
  }
}
```

```css
#RLAD {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}
```

```html
<button id="RLAD-wrapper">
click me
</button>
<div id="RLAD"></div>
<div>
content
</div>
```